# Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: java, jquery, cross-domain

Hi I'm developing a web application using a REST web service as server side. When I make a call to rest web service from my client side it gives me the following error. Servie is running uder `http://localhost:8010/service` and client is running under `http://localhost:8020/client`. I have deployed this in jetty.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8010/Service/rest/employee/basicupdate. Origin http://localhost:8020 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Below I have included my rest method

```
@POST
@Path("/basicupdate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Context 
public String isValidLogin(@FormParam("employeeId") int employeeId, @FormParam("firstName") String firstName, @FormParam("lastName") String lastName, @FormParam("gender") String gender, @FormParam("dob") String dob ) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    Response response = new Response();
    String responseString = "";
    try {

        //Application logic

        response.setCode(MessageCode.SUCCESS);
        response.setMessage("Successfully Updated");

    } catch (CustomException e) {
        response.setCode(MessageCode.ERROR);
        response.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setCode(MessageCode.ERROR);
        response.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        responseString = mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
    }   
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<web-app>
 <filter>
   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I have another question. Now this is working fine. When I post the request the web service update the required data and send me the response without any error. The response status is also 200. But this response come to error method of the jquery method without success. What could be the reason?

Comment: You dont give any details about which REST framework you're using.